# Nitrogen chain nomenclature

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, nomenclature, pnictogen

I know that nitrogen is versatile enough that it can form branched chains if it is all single bonds.

For example:

$\ce{H2N-N(NH2)-NH2}$

Is this compound a nitrane (nitrogen alkane)?

If so how would I name this branched nitrogen compound?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [IUPAC Gold book](http://goldbook.iupac.org/A00553.html), these are known as **azanes**, from the information:

> Saturated acyclic nitrogen hydrides having the general formula $\ce{N_{n}H_{n + 2}}$

For the example you are looking at, according to the IUPAC document [P-67 Mononuclear and polynuclear noncarbon acids and their functional replacement
analogues as parents for naming organic compounds](http://old.iupac.org/reports/provisional/abstract04/BB-prs310305/Chapter6-Sec67.pdf) (p. 15) is named as **2-aminotriazane**.

Comment: Additionally, it is probably going to explode.

Comment: This is a substance that I am definitely not keen on being around.

Comment: Yeah I can see why azanes would be explosive.